# How select users where with paid is true and paid_subscriptions expirence_at current date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have **model User**

```
has_many: paid_subscriptions
```

model  **PaidSubscription**

```
belongs_to :user
```

How me write active record query for select all users, where `paid` is `true` and `paid_subscriptions` `expirence_at` < current day?

**EDIT:**

```
User.includes(:paid_subscriptions).where("YEAR(created_at) = ? AND active = ?", 2011, true).where('paid_subscriptions.expirence_at < ?', Date.today)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
User.includes(:paid_subscriptions)
    .where('YEAR(users.created_at) = ? AND users.active = ? and paid_subscriptions.expirence_at < ?', 2011, true, Date.today)
```

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @Dimitri: there is no `created_at` in my query, can you show your code?

Comment: please check in body question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

`user.rb`

```
has_many :paid_subscriptions
scope :paid, -> { where(paid: true) }
```

`paid_subscription.rb`

```
belongs_to :user
scope :past, -> { where('experience_at < ?', Date.today) }
```

your query in the action

```
User.paid.joins(:paid_subscriptions).merge(PaidSubscription.past)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
User.find(:all, includes: paid_subscriptions, conditions: ["paid_subscriptions.expirence_at < ?", Time.now.todate])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. How and why does this help the OP with his problem? Can you please elaborate?